# ruby on rails syntax- when does : come before v. after the variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Probably obvious; I'm pretty new to Rails.

My question: is there a rule or an easier way to remember when a colon comes before or after a variable? Here's an example of what I'm talking about from my `application_controller`.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

I'm referring to the `with:` v. the `:exception`.

Is there a way to remember when the colon comes at the end, and when it comes at the beginning, or is it just something you memorize on a variable-by-variable basis? Also, why are both found in a row here?

I really want to understand this :) thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `with: :exception` is just syntactic sugar for `:with => :exception`

There is no real benefit to this other than convenience and less typing.  The argument could be made if you need to continue supporting ruby 1.8 you should just continue using the old syntax since.

You have to realize in the example you provided

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

This is a method that is being passed a single variable, which happens to be a hash.  So the following are equivalent.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
protect_from_forgery(with: :exception)
protect_from_forgery(:with => :exception)
protect_from_forgery({:with => :exception})
```

As I progress down the line notice each is a bit more typing, but they are all doing the same thing.  Each passes a hash with a single key/value pair to protect_from_forgery.

Going back to your original question of left vs right, just keep in mind the left is your key AND it is a symbol.

So the following examples are all valid hashes.

```
foo = {bar: "baz"}
foo = {bar: 1}
foo = {bar: :baz}
foo = {bar: some_object}
```

Then realizing that this is shortcut for a symbol key hashing to some thing, symbol, number, string, object, etc... this can replace the old syntax of {:bar => some_thing}

If your key is something other than a symbol you will need to use the old syntax.

```
foo = {1 => :bar}
foo = {"string" => some_object}
```

Comment: which is a syntax sugar for `{:with => :exception}`.

Comment: Syntactic sugar means one thing is the same as the other thing, but less work. For a more complete explanation on syntactic sugar see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar.

Comment: @sawa, agreed.  See the additional information I provided.  Since the hash is the last argument the braces are dropped off as a matter of convenience, but I'm pretty sure you already know that ;)

Comment: You missed the colons before `exception`.

Answer (score 3):

If we added all the symbols we omitted here, as Ruby syntax allows, we'd get something like this:

```
protect_from_forgery( { :with => :exception } )
```

Where `{ :with => :exception }` is a hashmap, commonly called "hash" among Ruby devs: a set of key-value pairs. Here, we have a hash with one pair: value `:exception` by key `:with`.

If a hash is the last argument in a method call, enclosing a hash in `{}` is not necessary. So, let's omit curly braces now:

```
protect_from_forgery( :with => :exception )
```

This looks a bit ugly, so many characters that are just part of Ruby syntax. But if in a pair of values (`key => value`) key is a symbol (`:thing`), there is an alternate syntax in Ruby for defining a key-value pair:

```
protect_from_forgery( with: :exception )
```

However, in many code samples around the internet this alternate syntax is not used. Apparently in favor of compatibility with older versions of Ruby (prior to 1.9). Today, in most cases using such old versions of Ruby is impractical, so it's up to personal taste now.

And sometimes we can omit parentheses enclosing arguments, as long as that doesn't make code ambiguous or less readable. Here it doesn't. But be extra careful with this feature, if you ever decide to use it yourself.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

[Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens) advises to only omit parentheses if you're using some kind of DSL based on Ruby. The question is, what is to be considered a DSL and what is not. Here we could call this a "Rails controller definition DSL", we are describing a class by issuing a DSL's command. Could qualify as DSL usage.

Comment: Using hashes with braces but with the argument parentheses omitted is ungrammatical due to ambiguity with a block. If you change the order of your explanation (and the examples due to that), then it would be a good answer.

Comment: @sawa Fair enough, didn't think about the order, just published a breakdown on what syntactic constructs we have here. Now that you mention it, I've updated the answer with a slightly different order and some references.